# What library should I use to get earphone button click as an input?

Tags: android, android-library

I was developing an android app using android studio. The app is supposed to know when an earphone button is clicked to do some actions. If there is a library that lets you get button click as an input I need to know what it is. If there is any one that had encountered what I have encountered and found a solution please share the resources.

Comment: Questions asking for off-site resources (such books/tutorials, tools/libraries) are off-topic here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For questions like this, refer to the Android SDK Documentation: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media-apps/mediabuttons

There are code examples in both Kotlin and Java that show how to intercept and react to the `KeyEvent`s that correspond to media button clicks.

P.S. I googled "android media control api"